# Unable to run systrace on Note 10.1

Tags: android, systrace

```
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/print-tgid: Permission denied (13)
```

unable to start tracing

I am getting the above error when trying to run systrace on my Note 10.1 2014 device. Any ideas?

I followed the steps from google outlined here:

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html

Comment: systrace may not be enabled in the kernel on that device.

Comment: @fadden By any chance do you know if the Nexus 10 kernel supports systrace? I'm trying to run systrace on my Nexus 10 and am getting the exact same error message as the OP.

Comment: So long as you're running the stock version of Android, it should definitely be supported.  Some features do require root -- try dropping "sched".

Comment: .@AlexLockwood, did you ever get Systrace working on your Nexus 10?  I'm running Stock Android on mine and I can get it to work - same error as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to some of categories that you have selected. some of the categories need root permissions.

use following command to check what all categories that current device can support.

```
$python systrace.py -l 

     gfx - Graphics
   input - Input
    view - View System
 webview - WebView
      wm - Window Manager
      am - Activity Manager
      sm - Sync Manager
   audio - Audio
   video - Video
  camera - Camera
     hal - Hardware Modules
     app - Application
     res - Resource Loading
  dalvik - Dalvik VM
      rs - RenderScript
  bionic - Bionic C Library
   power - Power Management
```

root and remount the device before running above command.

```
adb root
adb remount
```